# Can't get CollectionField to work in EasyAdmin 3.0

Tags: easyadmin

I am trying to use "Tags" in my Account Entity.
So

1. I have Entity "Account"
2. I have Entity "Tag"
3. In "Account" Entity, I have

```
        /**
        * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity=Tag::class, inversedBy="accounts")
        * @ORM\JoinTable(name="account_tag")
        */
        private $tags;
```

4. In "Tag" entity I have

```
          /**
          * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity=Account::class, mappedBy="tags")
          */
          private $accounts;
```

5. In my AccountCrudController => ConfigureFields, I use "CollectionField" for my "tags" property

```
         public function configureFields(string $pageName): iterable
         {
            return [

                 TextField::new('name'),
                  AssociationField::new('owner'),
                  AssociationField::new('parent'),
                  CollectionField::new('tags'),
            ];
         }
```

6. I am getting below
   [Expected value of type "App\Entity\Tag" for association field "App\Entity\Account#$tags", got "string" instead.[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hcA48.png)

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to use an AssociationField here as well, which would fit your purpose.

AssociationField::new('tags') will allow you to reference **existing** Tags.

If you wish to create all new Tags together, you could use something like this as there is no way to add Tags on the fly in the AssociationField at the moment.

Have you tried setting your CollectionField like this:

```
CollectionField::new('tags')
            ->allowAdd()
            ->allowDelete()
            ->setEntryType(TagType::class)
        ;
```

The important part is the TagType where you define your own FormType. I am also trying to implement this feature, so if you have a fully working example, let us know!